# error LNK2005: already defined on including a header file twice

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, include, lnk2005

I need to edit and access a few variables across multiple cpp files in a visual studio project. So I created a header file with a namespace containing all the variables I require as follows:

```
namespace windowdimension{
    TCHAR openwindows[20][180];
    int winnum = 0;
    int windowleft = 0;
    int windowright = 1360;
    INT windowtop = 0;
    INT windowbottom = 768;
    LONG leftarray[20];
    LONG rightarray[20];
    LONG toparray[20];
    LONG bottomarray[20];

}
```

However if I `#include` this header file in two source files, I get this linker error 2005 saying the parameter was already defined in the other obj.

On referring to other question of the same error, I got to know [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11938865/5391582) that

> a function definition can only appear once. Every .cpp file that #includes your .h file will generate yet another copy of the function.

But does that hold for namespace variables as well?
If so how do we ensure access to a particular variable across multiple source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never define global variables in a header file.

To be able to share, you need to declare them in a header file (using `extern` keyword), and define only once in a .cpp file.

Sure, never forget about include guards in every header file (`#pragma once` is pretty portable solution):

global.hpp

```
#pragma once

namespace global {
   extern int variable;
}
```

global.cpp

```
namespace global {
   int variable = 0;
}
```

Anyway, it is a very bad practice to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add an *include guard*:

#### Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

namespace something {
}

#endif
```

Another option is to use `#pragma once` in the very beginning of your header file.